# How to access pop up button element in swift and use it in calculations?

Tags: swift

I am new to swift. Wrote the code for the calculation. I do not understand how to access the popup button element that is selected and use it in calculations? Here is the code:

```
//  GlasgoScaleCalculatorViewController.swift
//  MedicalCalc
//
//  Created by Andrei Dokuchaev on 30.12.2022.
//

import UIKit

class GlasgoScaleCalculatorViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       setPopUpButton()
      
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var otkrivanieGlas: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var resultKomaField: UILabel!
    
    
    func setPopUpButton() {
        
        let optionClosure = {(action : UIAction) in
            print(action.title)}
        
    
        otkrivanieGlas.menu = UIMenu(children : [
            UIAction(title : "Item1", state : .on, handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Item2", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Item3", handler : optionClosure),
            UIAction(title : "Item4", handler : optionClosure)
        ])
        
    
        otkrivanieGlas.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
        otkrivanieGlas.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true
        
        
    }
   
    
    var otkrivanGlasSelected: Double = 0
    
    var resultKomaGlasgoSelect: String = ""

 @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    
     // calculate function

    if otkrivanieGlas. == 0 { // ??? 
         
    }

         
     }
    
    }
    
}
```

The selectedSegmentIndex method doesn't work because it doesn't exist in UIButton. Help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I used currentTitle

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it solved the problem.